# Правильно ли я использую БЭМ?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, бэм, site

Я только начал изучать БЭМ, сверстал часть сайта и пробовал по максимуму использовать БЭМ.
Я не могу понять, правильно ли я делаю?

ссылка на макет: https://www.figma.com/file/5D9pDuLtS042hzaoN69Kd7/Free--Landing--Page-Template?node-id=254%3A515&t=v9pAJcIsesh18Ttq-0

```css
@import url(reset.css);

/* font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gilroy-Heavy', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gilroy-Light', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Gilroy-Regular', sans-serif; */

.container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1445px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menu {
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-left: 252px;
}

.menu__list {
    display: flex;
}

.menu__item {
    margin-right: 155px;
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    color: #828282;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__item-link {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #828282;
}

.menu__item-link--active {
    color: #000;
}

.menu__line {
    border: 1px solid #828282;
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    width: 940.6px;
    margin-top: 31px;
}

.header__content-title {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 47px;
    line-height: 59px;
    margin-top: 39px;
}

.header__content-sub-title {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin-top: 94px;
    margin-left: 297px;
}

.header__container {
    display: flex;
}

.header__content-langwich {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 350px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.header__content-langwich-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #828282;
}

.header__content-langwich-link--active {
    color: #000000;
}

.header__content-img {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.about {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 1445px;
    height: 506px;
    margin-top: 104px;
}

.section-about {
    height: 506px;
}

.title {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 43px;
    text-align: center;
}

.title__about {
    padding-top: 120px;
}

.sub-title {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21px;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-title__about {
    padding-top: 17px;
}

.title__skills {
    margin-top: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 69px;
}

.programs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 83px;
}

.programs__img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.programs__text {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #828282;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.programs__stars {
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.star {
    margin-right: 9px;
}

.programs__block {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 45px;
}

.portfolio {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 1445px;
    height: 2253px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

.portfolio__title {
    padding-top: 112px;
    padding-bottom: 47px;
}

.portfolio__link {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 21.83px;
    color: #070707;
}

.portfolio__text {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 44px;
    margin-bottom: 99px;
}

.portfolio__img {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.message__title {
    margin-top: 114px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.message__sub-title {
    margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.message__button {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 180px;
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #070707;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 85px;
}

.icons__list {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icons__item {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px 30px 45px 30px;
}

.icons__sub-title {
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 123px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
        <link
            href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/gilroy-bold"
            rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <title>БЭМ</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="menu">
                    <lu class="menu__list">
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a
                                class="menu__item-link menu__item-link--active"
                                href="#"
                                >Home</a
                            >
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link" href="#">About me</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link" href="#">Skills</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu__item">
                            <a class="menu__item-link" href="#">Contacts</a>
                        </li>
                    </lu>
                    <div class="menu__line"></div>
                    <div class="header__content">
                        <div class="header__container">
                            <div class="header__content-title">
                                Denis <br />
                                Novik
                            </div>
                            <div class="header__content-sub-title">
                                UX | UI designer <br />
                                24 years old, Minsk
                            </div>
                            <div class="header__content-langwich">
                                <a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="header__content-langwich-link"
                                    >RU
                                </a>
                                <a
                                    href="#"
                                    class="header__content-langwich-link header__content-langwich-link--active"
                                    >| ENG</a
                                >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img
                            class="header__content-img"
                            src="/img/photo.jpg"
                            alt="img"
                        />
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <section class="section-about">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="about">
                    <div class="title__about">
                        <h1 class="title">About me</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sub-title__about">
                        <p class="sub-title">
                            Hi, I'm Denis – UX/UI designer from Minsk. <br />
                            I'm interested in design and everything connected
                            with it.
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            I'm studying at courses "Web and mobile design
                            <br />
                            interfaces" in IT-Academy. <br />
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            Ready to implement excellent projects <br />
                            with wonderful people.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section-skills">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="skills">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1 class="title__skills">Skills</h1>
                    </div>
                    <p class="sub-title">I work in such programs as</p>
                </div>
                <div class="programs">
                    <div class="programs__block">
                        <div class="programs__img">
                            <img
                                class="programs__img"
                                src="/img/PS.png"
                                alt="ps"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p class="programs__text">
                            Adobe <br />
                            Photoshop
                        </p>
                        <div class="programs__stars">
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img
                                class="star"
                                src="/img/Star-empty.png"
                                alt="star"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="programs__block">
                        <div class="programs__img">
                            <img
                                class="programs__img"
                                src="/img/AE.png"
                                alt="ai"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p class="programs__text">
                            Adobe <br />
                            Illustrator
                        </p>
                        <div class="programs__stars">
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img
                                class="star"
                                src="/img/Star-empty.png"
                                alt="star"
                            />
                            <img
                                class="star"
                                src="/img/Star-empty.png"
                                alt="star"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="programs__block">
                        <div class="programs__img">
                            <img
                                class="programs__img"
                                src="/img/AI.png"
                                alt="ae"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p class="programs__text">
                            Adobe <br />
                            After Effects
                        </p>
                        <div class="programs__stars">
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img
                                class="star"
                                src="/img/Star-empty.png"
                                alt="star"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="programs__block">
                        <div class="programs__img">
                            <img
                                class="programs__img"
                                src="/img/Figma.png"
                                alt="fig"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p class="programs__text">
                            Figma <br />
                             
                        </p>
                        <div class="programs__stars">
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img class="star" src="/img/Star.png" alt="star" />
                            <img
                                class="star"
                                src="/img/Star-empty.png"
                                alt="star"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="section-porftolio">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="portfolio">
                    <div class="portfolio__title">
                        <h1 class="title">Portfolio</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portfolio__concept">
                        <div class="portfolio__img">
                            <img src="/img/portfolio-photo1.png" alt="img" />
                        </div>
                        <p class="portfolio__text">
                            <a class="portfolio__link" href="#"
                                >Online fashion store - Homepage</a
                            >
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portfolio__concept">
                        <div class="portfolio__img">
                            <img src="/img/portfolio-photo2.png" alt="img" />
                        </div>
                        <p class="portfolio__text">
                            <a class="portfolio__link" href="#"
                                >Reebok Store - Concept</a
                            >
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portfolio__concept">
                        <div class="portfolio__img">
                            <img
                                class="portfolio__img"
                                src="/img/portfolio-photo3.png"
                                alt="img"
                            />
                        </div>
                        <p class="portfolio__text">
                            <a class="portfolio__link" href="#"
                                >Braun Landing Page - Concept</a
                            >
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="contacts">
                    <div class="message">
                        <div class="message__title">
                            <h1 class="title">Contacts</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message__sub-title">
                            <p class="sub-title">
                                Want to know more or just chat? <br />
                                You are welcome!
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <a class="message__button" href="#">Send message</a>
                        <div class="icons">
                            <lu class="icons__list">
                                <li class="icons__item">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="/img/link1.png" alt="img" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="icons__item">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="/img/link2.png" alt="img" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="icons__item">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="/img/link3.png" alt="img" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="icons__item">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="/img/link4.png" alt="img" />
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </lu>
                            <p class="icons__sub-title">
                                Like me on <br />
                                LinkedIn, Instagram, Behance, Dribble
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну, Вы верстаете неправильно, сначала бы нужно понять, что такое CSS (то, что есть адаптивная верстка, и пользоваться `absolute` для всего подряд нельзя, то что сейчас все верстается на flex и grid). А потом разбираться в БЭМ, и понять, что он для компонентного подхода (`.photoshop`, `.figma`, `.after-effects`, `.illustrator` - это всё один и тот же компонент, стили должны быть одинаковые)

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Я понимал что .photoshop, .figma, .after-effects, и .illustrator надо было сделать как один компонент. Но я не смог это реализовать

Comment: @morphw, почему _не смог это реализовать_? У тебя даже стили одни и те же получились

Comment: Дело в отступах. Отступ в .photoshop margin-left: 303px; а в .illustrator margin-left: 181px;
Из-за этого я сделал разные элементы.

Если сможете то пришлите пример как это надо было сделать. Спасибо!

Comment: @morphw, просто переделай компоненты и сделай отступы одинаковыми

Comment: Я довестрал сайт, и отредактировал некоторые моменты. новый код я разместил в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Там отступы по задумке одинаковые, соответственно в ограничивающий контейнер клади все и делай justify-content: space-beetwen. Почему они разные в макете - вопрос к дизайнеру который делал сайт. Если прям нужен pixel perfect - то просто отступы делай или модификатором или отдельным классом-утилитой и все. А чтобы не было схлопывания margin - не делай margin-left и margin-top, используй правило что элемент не может толкать сам себя, а только соседа справа и снизу.

Comment: Я довестрал сайт, и отредактировал некоторые моменты. новый код я разместил в вопросе.

Comment: 1.) Можно сокращать, не margin tight и margin left, а просто margin: 0 auto 2.) думай сразу об адаптиве и делай резину, не используй width, а max-width , %, ем, rem 3.) касаемо бэм позже скажу, если до этого никто не скажет) не удобно с телефона смотреть)

Comment: Спасибо, прислушаюсь к вашим советам!